# Count files in multiple subdirectories with different names

Tags: batch-file

My script is going to count files and it works I edit the script to work with one specific folder. The problem is the files I'm counting's directory.

This is the folders setup

```
\\server\Something\aaa\aaafolder
\\server\Something\bbb\bbbfolder
\\server\Something\ccc\cccfolder
```

Now I want all `*.*` in aaafolder, bbbfolder and cccfolder

This is what I've got

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=0 

for %%n IN (\\server\Something\???\???folder\*.*) DO ( 
      SET /A count=count + 1 
)
echo Number of files %count%
IF "%count%"=="100" Echo Too many files in queue
pause
```

This results in `0` from the `%count%`, so I assume something is wrong with the `for` line. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried multiple variations, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more errors in the code but this is what's obvious to me:

```
...

for %%n IN (\\server\Something\???\???folder\*.*) DO ( 
      SET /A count=!count!+1 
)
echo Number of files !count!
IF "!count!"=="100" Echo Too many files in queue
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this results the same. The problem lies at the "for" command/line since the count works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for /r "\\server\Something" %%n IN (.) DO (
```

I don't have access to a networked machine to try this  - but it should work.

The problem is that you can't use wildcards where you've tries to. This will count all of the files - do you actually want only the files in directories named *parentdirectory*folder to be counted?

Obfuscation leads to confusion.

Comment: Correct. I only want to count files in the current directory. Not any of the parentdirectories. The reasons for this are many.